# Liferay LAR export file gets bigger and bigger

Tags: export, liferay

I've got a *Liferay 6.2 CE GA 4* on a local and on a remote server.

I've uploaded 228 PDF files to 2 document folders on the local server and I exported these as a LAR file for import into the remote Liferay server.

The first time when the export finished I've got a LAR file of around 180 MB. I didn't download it because I had to upload 4 more files, and repeat the LAR export.

I uploaded the 4 files, but had no time to export immediately.

3 hours later when I exported the LAR file again, the size was already at 270MB. I thought it got bigger because of the generated previews files, so I waited and repeated the LAR export a day later. Now the LAR file grew to 2.4 GB!

Looking into the LAR file I found out that all my PDF files had 2 - 400 KB preview pages attached to it. Is there anything I can do to decrease the size of the LAR export?

Comment: You know that a LAR is just a ZIP file? You can extract the files and check which ones are the reason for the explosion.

Comment: Thanks Tobias! It's a good starting point!

Comment: You woul'nt beleive it! I foud that all my PDF-s had 2-400Kbyte/page preview pages... so Liferay made my 228 pieces 160MB PDFs into 2.7G datda. Nice... Good bye LAR export/import :(

Comment: To have a question that I can answer in the format of Stackoverflow, I reworded your original post a little bit. I hope that I've got your intentions right.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options that could fit more or less your problem.

If you don't need any preview and thumbnail images at all, you can turn them off in your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
# Turns off all preview files for all file types (including PDF files)
dl.file.entry.preview.enabled = false

# Turns off all thumbnail files for all file types (including PDF files)
dl.file.entry.thumbnail.enabled = false
```

Or you turn off the PDF processing for all PDF files by removing `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.PDFProcessorImpl` from `dl.file.entry.processors` in the same file.

Or you set the maximum file size that triggers preview and thumbnail generation to a small value, say 200Kb:

```
dl.file.entry.previewable.processor.max.size = 204800
```

Or you decrease the file size of all preview files by changing the image resolution (same for thumbnail):

```
dl.file.entry.preview.document.max.width=200
```

As last option you could write your own export action:

```
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
// Turn off export of preview / thumbnail files
parameterMap.put("_document_library_previews-and-thumbnails", new String[] { "false" });
...
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.exportLayouts(..., parameterMap, ...)
```